# What forums are there for people interested in a plant-based diet?

Tags: weight, vegetarianism, weight-loss, body-weight

I'm working with someone who's trying to lose weight by switching to a plant-based diet.

She could use some people to talk to who also have plant-based diets.

By 'plant-based' she means mostly vegetarian, but not strictly meat-free.

Do you know any forums she can go to?